# Converting null/empty fields to the value from another field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In an MS Access 2010 database, `SomeTable` has two fields named `Field1` and `Field2`.  The actual data always includes values for `Field1`, but there are often missing values for `Field2`.  Both `Field1` and `Field2` have text datatype.

**What specific syntax is required for an SQL statement that will 1.) look for null/empty(e.g. "") values in `Field2` and then 2.) paste the value from `Field1` into `Field2` if and only if `Field2` was empty or null?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a select query, you would use the `nz()` function:

```
select nz(field2, field1)
```

You can use this function in an update as well, but you wouldn't need it:

```
update table t
    set field2 = field1
    where field2 is null;
```

Answer (score 3):

If *Field2* may include both Null and zero-length string (`''`), and you want both those cases treated the same, target them with the expression `Len(Field2 & '') = 0`.

You can then use that as the condition in an `IIf()` expression in a `SELECT` query:

```sql
SELECT IIf(Len(Field2 & '') = 0, Field1, Field2)
```

Or for an `UPDATE` query, just put it in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
UPDATE SomeTable
SET Field2 = Field1
WHERE Len(Field2 & '') = 0;
```

Comment: Since your Access version is 2010, you could use a data macro in an ACCDB format database to keep *Field2* updated as you wish, and not need to do it with SQL.  However, your db would not then be usable in Access 2007 if that's a concern.